# ios: how to stop output of a show command

Tags: command-line-interface, ios

Can anyone tell me how to break output of a show command in cisco ios?

Say I don't want to see all of 'show run' and I got the info I need, what keys can I press to stop it from printing the rest of the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>q</kbd>

Comment: < thanks jscott for the cleanup... and the lesson >